# XForm in debian

Tags: debian, xmpp, xforms

I have a debian server with openfire.

I want to use xform mainly for bot development.I have executed following command.

apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search xforms

When I do "apt-file search xforms", I get several results.

I have searched for the example and found out following code.

```
<message from="sender@wonderland.lit/foo" to="receiver@wonderland.lit/bar">
<x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
<title>My Special Form</title>   
<field label="Text Input" type="text-single" var="field-1"/>
</x>
</message>
```

But it is not displaying anything and there is no error.

Please guide me on this.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

You've to interface your webserver with an xslt processor.
If you not using apache-cocoon, you probably can use apache+php (with php-xsl module).
Please follow the XForms doc on php site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck with this one, there are now at least two client-based XForm implementations:

https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-4345

As a new user, I get only one hyperlink. So, search on "agence.xml" or "Alain Couthurse"